# не возвращаются данные отправленные на сервер

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, socket.io

В чате отправляя текст на сервер,оттуда отправляю в базу данных,и хочу вернуть его сразу на клиентскую страницу,но данные выводятся только после перезагрузки сервера, как исправить ситуацию?

сервер app.js

```
   io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
   var name = 'U' + (socket.id).toString().substr(1, 4);
   socket.emit('allMessage', await con.then(function (res) {

     return res;
    })); // При соеденении я на клиенте получаю все сообщения.


   socket.broadcast.emit('newUser', name);

   socket.emit('userName', name);


   socket.on('message', async function (msg) {
    InData.insert(msg, name, "Sex"); // Добовляю в базу данных
    socket.emit('messageToclient',await con.newSelect.then(function (res) {
        return res; // После добовления в базу данных, снова делаю запрос 
    //что-бы язьять все данные  отправляю на клиента. Если посмотреть в 
    //бд,информация появилась. Если поставить вывод на самом сервере через 
    //console.log,то информация так же не обновляется.
    }));

});
});
```

main.js

```
var SelectChat = angular.module('SelectChat', 
['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when("/",{
templateUrl: 'index.html',
controller: 'NameInfo'
});
}]).factory('socket',['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
var port = 8080;
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:' + port);

 return {
on: function(eventName, callback) {
    socket.on(eventName,function(data){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){callback(data)});
    });
},
emit: function(eventName,data){
    socket.emit(eventName,data);
    console.log(data);
 }
 }
}]);
SelectChat.controller('NameInfo',function($scope,socket){


socket.on('userName',function(userName){
$scope.name = userName;
});

socket.on('newUser',function(newUser){
//$scope.newUsername = newUser;
});

socket.on('allMessage',function(date){
$scope.text = date.rows;
});

socket.on('messageToclient',function(date){

 $scope.text = date.rows;
console.log(date.rows);

});

$(document).on('click','button',function(){

var message = $('input').val();
socket.emit('message',message);
$('input').val(null);
 });

});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>chat</title>
<script src="javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="javascripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Здесь можете подключить ваш main.css -->
</head>
<body >
<header >
<h1>Chat</h1>
</header>

<main ng-app="SelectChat">
<div ng-controller="NameInfo">
<p ng-repeat="texts in text">{{texts.text}}/</p>

 </div>

</main>
<footer>
<input type="text" name="text" size="100">
<button type="button" name="button" id="sendMsg">Отправить</button>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас, если честно, какая-то каша :-) Где у вас код на сервере, который выводит все сообщения? Где на клиенте подпись на событие `messageToclient`?

Comment: Исправил, изначально забыл добавить в вопрос.

Comment: Где у вас код на сервере, который выводит все сообщения?

Comment: Перезалил файл сервер. Я и до этого вылаживал полную форму, почему так выложило не пойму.

Comment: При старте сервера выводя в consol.log  я получаю ответ от бд. На клиентской части я отправляю сообщение, записал в бд, убедился что она там есть. Обновляю страницу клиента, данные не обновленные.  Второй раз не срабатывает этот фрагмент кода socket.emit('allMessage', await con.then(function (res) {

     return res;
    }));

Comment: `InData.insert` - это асинхронная операция возможно.